# How to create array of pointers to stackalloc 'buffers'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Wanting to create an array containing 4 unique pointers to 4 unique buffers, created with stackalloc, but it's failing with "can't convert type of `<float>` to `float*`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
  float*[] auBuffers = new float*[4];
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < auBuffers.Length ; i++ ) {
    auBuffers[i] = stackalloc float[256];
  }
```

**UPDATE::**

Feel a bit silly for having asked this, but someone else might need it, so here's the workaround that I used to get this working:

```
  float*[] auBuffers = new float*[4];
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < auBuffers.Length ; i++ ) {
    float* tempau = stackalloc float[256];
    auBuffers[i] = tempau;
  }
```

Comment: It will compile if you do this: `var pointer = stackalloc float[256]; auBuffers[i] = pointer;`. I don't know why it doesn't work inline though

Comment: Cheers! I found this right after asking the question. Don't know why I didn't think to try it before hand. Same as you, baffled I couldn't do it inline. Tried every thing else to get this to work... then posted the question... and almost immediately realised I should try making a temp...

Comment: Your "workaround" is holding to a pointer to memory that's no longer valid.  This is exactly the kind of thing that C# does it's best to try to prevent you from doing, using unsafe code to do it anyway is a sign that you're probably better off sticking to managed code.

Comment: @Servy can you please explain the "no longer valid" part? Cause [next code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAULIGYAE4UQOywN6wJCKQFcA7AZwEMAzAUzQDYUAWJAWXIEtiAKASjxxi5clADYB7cgBckAKgDaAXSTlCAIUKUaAJ1JIAvEmLUA7klETp8xgoDceYWK1Iunae31IADDaTuAPMpqGtqkAHQAMtTEAOaSABY+7ADUSXyCuAJCwuJSspLUALYADioepJLkAMYA1uQi4pVmOZJyYACsdLawSD29fT0gEACcXFwAksSSAAqSWjz5xSo8dum4Kuqa1Dpy7EoGCyWEK0IAvrD268FbpHKeCrd7SBDH+MNcl5vbEPd3y0gA9P8kEUtK5dJ57IMRh8Qg8Hn9AcDQZNdNBBGcYCcgA===) gives output which I expect. What am I missing here?

Comment: @GuruStron You're storing a pointer to a local variable after it has gone out of scope.  You're not supposed to do that.  When you do that just about anything can happen.  If you were writing managed code it would *reliably* stop you from doing it (or extend the lifetime of the variable, depending on the context), as you're using unsafe code it doesn't stop you despite it not being valid.  Again, this is why you should be sticking to managed code if you think it's okay to access out of scope memory with pointers.

Comment: The whole point of this is to create four buffers in the outer scope! The for loop is only an inner scope because there's other things to be done configuring that outer scope that are best done in a for loop, to impact and be used in the outer scope. I'm not sure why you're instantly concerned about the scope, rather than the objective.

Comment: @Servy Can you please dumb it down a little bit more for me? While the variable has gone out of scope - the allocated memory has not, as the reference to it. What are possible problems here?

Comment: @Confused The scope matters because the memory is free to be used by *whatever the operating system wants to use it for* once the variable has left scope.

Comment: @GuruStron Were this a traditional array allocated on the heap, then yes, the array's lifetime can be an indeterminate amount of time, and you can hold a reference to it as long as you want and the act of holding a reference to it will keep it alive.  That's only true *with a managed array and managed references*.  None of that is true for unamanged pointers (not references) to stack (not heap) storage.  The problems are this is undefined behavior.  You're accessing arbitrary memory addresses that aren't valid.  Practically anything can happen when you do that.

Comment: @GuruStron What do you think `stackalloc` (and the use of pointers rather than references) does?  If you think it behaves exactly like a regular array using managed references and allocated on the heap, then *what do you think these tools do*, and why do you think they're being used?

Comment: @Servy No, I don't think that it behaves as managed ones. I don't understand why are they invalid inside the same method? Scope of variable does not determine stack reference, i.e. in my code example `tempau` going out of scope (at the end of `for`) will not cause the cahnge of stack pointer, cause it still will be in the same stack frame. At least it is my understanding of it. So if `auBuffers` is for "local" use only it should just fine. Maybe changing `auBuffers` to something like `float** auBuffers = stackalloc float*[4]` to kind of guarantee that is better idea than using ordinary array.

Comment: @GuruStron whenever you see this: "You're not supposed to do that. " bereft of any consideration or insight into the objective, you can tune out. "rules" in programming only exist to the extent which they're helpful, and are (like all rules) meant to be broken. Further, without an exact demonstration of where that context exists (its bounds and happenstances) there's no point guessing at intent, objective, benefits, risks and rewards for any (ab)use of any technique and/or technology.

Comment: Most IDEs will remind you that it _might_ be a problem to create stackallocs within a for loop, too. Which it might be, if you're not doing it in a guarded manner, or with limited values that can't blow out and cause a ***stackoverflow***. But, if you have considered this, then the performance benefits can be an order of magnitude, or two.

Comment: In this case, the context isn't shown, and that's my fault. I probably should have wrapped all this in the method, which is a callback from Unity. (OnAudioFilterRead), which is called by Unity each time it's in need of a block of audio data. We (the users) must provide that data, and the method call is done. This happens about every 1/42nd to 1/172nd of a second, depending on dspBufferSize. Everything stackalloc'd within this callback is lost to the stack at the end of each call. Gone! So long as we know that, these are fantastically fast little temp buffers. And very useful for summing fast!